# ReplyingKafkaTemplate / KafkaTemplate not sending / receiving key

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a template that looks like this:

```
@Autowired
private ReplyingKafkaTemplate<ItemId, MessageBDto, MessageBDto> xxx2ReplyingKafkaTemplate;
```

My send wrapper method looks like this:

```
public RequestReplyFuture<ItemId, MessageBDto, MessageBDto> sendAndReceiveMessageB(MessageBDto message) {
    ProducerRecord<ItemId, MessageBDto> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(KafkaTopicConfig.xxx2_TOPIC, new ItemId(message.getCount()), message);
    producerRecord.headers().add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC, KafkaTopicConfig.xxx2_REPLY_TOPIC.getBytes()));
    return this.xxx2ReplyingKafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(producerRecord);
}
```

And this is my listener:

```
@SendTo
@KafkaListener(topics=KafkaTopicConfig.xxx2_TOPIC, containerFactory="xxx2ListenerContainerFactory")
public MessageBDto xxx2Listener(ConsumerRecord<ItemId, MessageBDto> message) {
    System.out.println("xxx2(value): " + message.value().getMessage() + ", " + message.value().getCount());
    message.value().setCount(message.value().getCount() * 2);
    return message.value();
}
```

Isn't this supposed to send a Key=ItemId, Value=MessageBDto and receive the key in the listener?

The listener doesn't seem to get the key and/or it seems to be another instance of MessageBDto.

Am I misunderstanding how this is supposed to work?

EDIT:

PRODUCER Beans:

```
@Bean
public ProducerFactory<ItemId, MessageBDto> xxx2ProducerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<ItemId, MessageBDto>(super.producerConfigs(),
                                                                new JsonSerializer<ItemId>(),
                                                                new JsonSerializer<MessageBDto>());
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<ItemId, MessageBDto> xxx2ConsumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(super.consumerConfigs(),
                                             trustingDeserializer(ItemId.class),
                                             trustingDeserializer(MessageBDto.class));
}

@Bean
public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<ItemId, MessageBDto> dtms2MessageListenerContainer() {
    return new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(xxx2ConsumerFactory(),
                                               new ContainerProperties(KafkaTopicConfig.xxx2_REPLY_TOPIC));
}

@Bean
public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<ItemId, MessageBDto, MessageBDto> xxx2ReplyingKafkaTemplate() {
    return new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(xxx2ProducerFactory(), xxx2MessageListenerContainer());
}

private <T> JsonDeserializer<T> trustingDeserializer(Class<T> targetType) {
    JsonDeserializer<T> deserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>(targetType);
    deserializer.addTrustedPackages("*");
    return deserializer;
}
```

CONSUMER BEANS:

```
@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<ItemId, MessageBDto> xxx2KafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(xxx2ProducerFactory());
}

@Bean
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ItemId, MessageBDto> xxxListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<ItemId, MessageBDto> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(dtms2ConsumerFactory());
    factory.setReplyTemplate(xxx2KafkaTemplate());
    return factory;
}
```

When I look in the debugger, of my listener, it's showing that key is an empty instance of MessageBDto???

Versions:

- Apache Zookeeper 3.5.7
- Apache Kafka 2.12-2.4.0
- Spring Boot 2.2.4

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.2.RELEASE</version> <!-- $NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version> <!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>  <!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
  </dependency>
  ```

Comment: It should if everything is configured correctly. What version are you using? Also show your producer and consumer configurations. You are only returning the value so the key won't get back to the sender.

Comment: @GaryRussell When I view in the debugger on a breakpoint in the consumer, it shows that key is an empty instance of MessageBDto.

Comment: @GaryRussell I shutdown Kafka and Zookeeper and cleared out all the log and data files to make sure I didn't have anything bad in there... same thing... empty MessageBDto for the key, populated MessageBDto for the value.

Comment: @GaryRussell I also had a question about the return... you said I'm not returning the key... what I am supposed to return? A ProducerRecord object?

Comment: @GaryRussell I ran kafka-console-consumer with --property print.key=true and its sending the right key... so it seems like its something on the listener side??

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what's going on with your code. Here is a working example...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So60384112Application {


    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So60384112Application.class);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So60384112Application.class, args).close();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so60384112").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic replies() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so60384112replies").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so60384112", topics = "so60384112")
    @SendTo
    public Message<?> listen(ConsumerRecord<Foo, Bar> record) {
        LOG.info(record.key().toString() + ":" + record.value().toString());
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(new Bar(record.value().getField().toUpperCase()))
                .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, record.key())
                .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID, record.headers().lastHeader(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID).value())
                .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, record.headers().lastHeader(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC).value())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<Foo, Bar, Bar> replyer(ProducerFactory<Foo, Bar> pf,
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Foo, Bar> containerFactory) {

        containerFactory.setReplyTemplate(kafkaTemplate(pf));
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Foo, Bar> container = containerFactory.createContainer("so60384112replies");
        container.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("so60384112replies");
        ReplyingKafkaTemplate<Foo, Bar, Bar> replyer = new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, container);
        return replyer;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<Foo, Bar> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<Foo, Bar> pf) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(pf);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(ReplyingKafkaTemplate<Foo, Bar, Bar> template) {
        return args -> {
            RequestReplyFuture<Foo, Bar, Bar> future =
                    template.sendAndReceive(new ProducerRecord<>("so60384112", 0, new Foo("foo"), new Bar("bar")));
            ConsumerRecord<Foo, Bar> record = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            LOG.info(record.key().toString() + ":" + record.value().toString());
        };
    }

}

class Foo {

    private String field;

    public Foo() {
    }

    public Foo(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public String getField() {
        return this.field;
    }

    public void setField(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName() + " [field=" + this.field + "]";
    }

}

class Bar  {

    private String field;

    public Bar() {
    }

    public Bar(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    public String getField() {
        return this.field;
    }

    public void setField(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName() + " [field=" + this.field + "]";
    }

}
```

```
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*

spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

> 2020-02-24 18:00:47.904  INFO 16591 --- [o60384112-0-C-1] com.example.demo.So60384112Application   : Foo [field=foo]:Bar [field=bar]
>
> 2020-02-24 18:00:47.915  INFO 16591 --- [           main] com.example.demo.So60384112Application   : Foo [field=foo]:Bar [field=BAR]

To return the key, you have to return a `Message<?>`. Unfortunately, you have to set headers for the reply topic and correlation too.

Comment: At long last, I found the issue. I cleaned up a bunch of stuff along the way :), but the main issue was that I was using the JsonStringMessageConverter() because it got around the trust issue. When I switched everything over to JsonSerializer, the key is getting set correctly.